# Catching HTTPoison errors with invalid port range

Tags: elixir, httpoison

Encountered a situation where the url passed to get contains an invalid port

```
iex> HTTPoison.get("http://example.com:650000")

** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :inet_tcp.do_connect/4
   (kernel) inet_tcp.erl:113: :inet_tcp.do_connect({127, 0, 0, 1}, 650000, [{:packet, :raw}, {:active, false}, :binary], 8000)
   (kernel) gen_tcp.erl:185: :gen_tcp.try_connect/6
   (kernel) gen_tcp.erl:163: :gen_tcp.connect/4
```

Seems that I am unable to catch/rescue from this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging deeper looks like the error comes from the fact that you use a port number that is bigger than the maximum accepted value.

The ports should be in range `0..65535`, if we go to source code of the function that threw the exception, we can notice the following:

```
do_connect(Addr = {A,B,C,D}, Port, Opts, Time)
  when ?ip(A,B,C,D), ?port(Port)
```

I cannot find the source for `?port`, however I'm sure that it checks that the port is within bounds (nonnegative and smaller than 65535).

Now the reason why you couldn't handle the error is because at some point `exit()` is called and [process exit](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/try-catch-and-rescue.html#exits) should be handled a little different:

```
try do
  result = HTTPoison.get "http://example.com:6500000"
catch
  :exit, reason -> reason
end
```

You encountered an error that is not handled by the `HTTPoison` library and is propagated to your application directly, since `exit` messages are propagated unless exits are [trapped](https://crypt.codemancers.com/posts/2016-01-24-understanding-exit-signals-in-erlang-slash-elixir/#trapping-exits).

PS: You shouldn't handle errors such as this in your application unless there is no other choice.

Comment: This would happen if and only `HTTPoison` application is started, what has been deprecated ages ago.

Comment: Also, this literally breaks OTP contracts, the underlying process gets crashed and never restarted AFAICT. The subsequent request to the remote would crash as well.

Comment: I suppose this is a bug from hackney, cannot tell for sure since I'm not very good at reading erlang code, `HTTPoison` is just a elixir wrapper over hackney.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Kernel.SpecialForms.try/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#try/1).

```rb
try do
  HTTPoison.get("http://example.com:650000")
rescue
  e in [FunctionClauseError] ->
    IO.inspect(e, label: "Error")
    nil
end

#⇒ Error: %FunctionClauseError{...}
```

Comment: or you can use implicit `try`, credo encourages using it.

Comment: @Daniel unless the result of call to `HTTPoison.get/1` is to be assigned to a variable and then somehow handled. We don’t know the context hence we cannot suggest an implicit `try`.

Comment: Trying to handle the error like this (not handled though):

    defp fetch(url) do
        try do
            Logger.info("Fetching #{url}")
            HTTPoison.get(url)
       rescue
            FunctionClauseError ->
                 Logger.error("Exception caught trying to invoke url #{url}")
                 {:error, ""}
       end
   end

Comment: Sorry for bad formatted comment, don't know to format a code block

Comment: “Not handled” meaning exactly what?

Comment: Rescue clause is never invoked

Comment: I have checked the code in the snippet; if it’s not invoked for you, the problem is induced.